# NSTimer selector keeps getting called even in the background

Tags: ios, timer, background

So, I have an `NSTimer` that is set to call a selector every second:

```
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
                                                 target:self
                                               selector:@selector(TimerSelector:)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                repeats:YES ];
```

This is all fine, but ever since I  updated to iOS 8, I've noticed that this selector keeps getting called even after the application goes to the background. I thought that it would eventually stop running, as I believe an iOS application isn't allowed run in the background without a reason, but the selector kept getting called. I tried keeping the application on and simulating memory warnings, but the selector kept getting called for over 6 hours.

This behavior was only exhibited in iOS 8 and not iOS 7. Is this normal? Did iOS 8 bring something new I'm not aware of?

Comment: i didnt understood what are u expecting .. are you expecting not run in background , so if it is running in background make a check timeSelector that if app is in foreground dont execute body of timeselector

Comment: Do you have any other processes purposefully running in the background?

Comment: Connected to Xcode? You should turn the timer off when the app goes to the background anyway...

Comment: @shujatAli I'm expecting it not to run in the background, as is described in the apple documentations and as it has been before iOS 8.

Comment: @LyndseyScott: No background processes I purposely run.

Comment: @Wain Connected to Xcode and otherwise. I was just curious as to whether this is normal / why this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like it might be an exciting and interesting change in iOS 8, but I'm afraid that it is just a bug in the simulator. There's no evidence of timers continuing to run in the background *on the device*, which is all that really matters.

The situation *on the device* is that, unless your app has some other reason to run in the background, the timer is paused while your app is in the background, and resumes when your app comes to the foreground, just as in the previous system.

In the iOS 8 *simulator*, however, there's a well-known bug (Apple shows awareness of it in Dev Forums posts from November and December 2014): tasks continue to run and are not suspended when the app is backgrounded. Take no notice! The simulator is just a simulator. Do your real testing on a device.

Comment: I'll file a bug report with Apple if you like.

Comment: Ooops, no I won't. Turns out this is a well-known bug. See this post: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1087348#1087348 And it isn't just a matter of timers; it's the whole business of tasks in general. I will modify my answer to mention that.

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but I don't remember this happening in the simulator on iOS 7, which is why I thought something was wrong. Thanks!

Comment: You are quite right. The bug is, as I said, in the iOS 8 simulator — not the iOS 7 simulator.